# I already asked , but how to access view page without id value in the url

Tags: php, yii2

my view.php

```
  <?php
    echo 
    Html::beginForm(['contactpersons/update'], 'post',['id' => 'update-form']) .
    '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="'.$model->id.'">
     <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById(\'update-form\').submit(); 
    return false;">Update</a>'. 
    Html::endForm(); 
    ?>   
    <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
        'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
        'data' => [
            'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
            'method' => 'post',
        ],
    ])
 ?>
```

my controller is

```
     public function actionView($id)
      {
         $model = $this->findModel($id);
         return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
       }
```

How to modify this for getting my view page without id value in the url.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although the question is not that clear for me. But are you talking about pagination. As in url.com/?id=X where `X` is page number. Is that what you need to know how to remove this id from URL ?

Comment: So, what's wrong with your first question? You even accepted an answer over there? Question spamming (creating several posts with the same questions) as NOT gonna go down well for you here on SO. You should delete this question and clearify the first one, if needed..

Comment: Not asking about pagination, i am asking about my url looks http:/example.com/basic/web/view/3 like this where 3 is the id value of the specified row. i want  http:/example.com/basic/web/view like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could change it like this

```
public function actionView($id = null) {
    $model = null;
    if ($id !== null) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
    }
    return $this->render('view', ['model' => $model]);
}
```

However in your view you execute the following code: `$model->id`
this won't work when the model isn't set yo anything. So you could create a new model (`$model = new ModelClass()`) when the $id is null.

Sidenote: this doesn't look like an view action but more like an edit action, so maybe change your action to `actionEdit()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to your browser by two methods - POST and GET. So, if you want to hide id parameter, then you need to send your id as POST parameter, which is bad solution - it's hard to implement, because POST is usally sends when you submit a form.